# SQL help - Need one row for each product, not one row for each attribute?

Tags: sql, opencart

I'm trying to query my opencart database and I want to get all the attributes in a row that pertain to that certain product(if that's possible).

Here is what I have so far. It provides all the attribute for each product but for each attribute it creates a whole new row. I want all the attributes in one row if possible.

Thanks!

```
SELECT
    product.product_id,
    product.model,
    product_description.name,
    attribute_description.name,
    text
FROM
    product,
    product_attribute,
    attribute,
    attribute_description,
    product_description
WHERE
    product.product_id = product_attribute.product_id AND
    product_attribute.attribute_id = attribute.attribute_id AND
    attribute_description.attribute_id = attribute.attribute_id AND
    product.product_id = product_description.product_id
order by 
    product_id, attribute_description.name;
```

Here's the updated code:

```
SELECT
    p.product_id,
    p.model,
    pd.name,
    GROUP_CONCAT(ad.name ORDER BY ad.name SEPARATOR ',') AS attributes_group,
    GROUP_CONCAT(pa.text ORDER BY ad.name SEPARATOR ',') AS attributes
FROM product p
    LEFT JOIN product_attribute pa ON p.product_id = pa.product_id
    LEFT JOIN attribute_description ad ON pa.attribute_id = ad.attribute_id
    LEFT JOIN product_description pd ON p.product_id = pd.product_id
GROUP BY
    p.product_id, p.model, pd.name
ORDER BY
    p.product_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is to aggregate them together.  You should learn proper `join` syntax, but I'm not going to fix that here (put the join conditions in the `on` clause rather than the `where` clause).

Here is the MySQL syntax to do what you want:

```
SELECT
    product.product_id,
    product.model,
    product_description.name,
    group_concat(attribute_description.name) as attributes,
    text
FROM
    product,
    product_attribute,
    attribute,
    attribute_description,
    product_description
WHERE
    product.product_id = product_attribute.product_id AND
    product_attribute.attribute_id = attribute.attribute_id AND
    attribute_description.attribute_id = attribute.attribute_id AND
    product.product_id = product_description.product_id
group by 
    product.product_id,
    product.model,
    product_description.name;
```

If you are not using MySQL, most other databases have a similar function for concatenating string values in an aggregation.

Comment: That gave me the exact same results that I was getting with the code I posted.

Comment: @BobbyLipps . . . In that case, `text` is probably coming from the attributes table.  Given that I was using MySQL syntax, I just removed it from the `group by` clause.  In other databases, you would need to use `min()` or `max()`.

Comment: Hello, I removed the group by and it helped a little I suppose. It put all the attribute names in one table cell and I can't tell but I think it did the same thing for the text column. Lastly, it only returned one column.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at Your query I realize that You have probably never heard of `JOIN` in SQL queries...

So here is Your query rewritten using `JOIN`s:

```
SELECT
    p.product_id,
    p.model,
    pd.name,
    ad.name,
    pd.text /* <- don't know where the column is coming from, probably something custom */
FROM product p
    LEFT JOIN product_attribute pa ON p.product_id = pa.product_id
    LEFT JOIN attribute_description ad ON pa.attribute_id = ad.attribute_id
    LEFT JOIN product_description pd ON p.product_id = pd.product_id
PRDER BY
    p.product_id, ad.name
```

Now, using `JOIN`s, this query would be much quicker (depending on the total amount of rows).

**To Your question:** it is possible to load all of the attributes as one row using [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function:

```
SELECT
    p.product_id,
    p.model,
    pd.name AS product_name,
    GROUP_CONCAT(ad.name ORDER BY ad.name SEPARATOR ',') AS attributes,
    pd.text /* <- don't know where the column is coming from, probably something custom */
FROM product p
    LEFT JOIN product_attribute pa ON p.product_id = pa.product_id
    LEFT JOIN attribute_description ad ON pa.attribute_id = ad.attribute_id
    LEFT JOIN product_description pd ON p.product_id = pd.product_id
GROUP BY
    p.product_id, p.model, pd.name, pd.text
ORDER BY
    p.product_id
```

In `PHP` You then could just echo the '$result['attributes']`or`explode`it to get array of the attributes`$attributes = explode(',', $result['attributes']);`. Anyway, I guess You are wise of the fact that You are loading just the attribute names, not the actual attribute-value pairs...

---

**Edit:**

You can export into CSV only a plain structures (one entry per one row) - exactly what You are requesting. Plain structure means like `product` + `product_description`, or `category` + `category_description`. If You add `attribute` + `attribute_value` + `attribute_description` tables, the structure is not plain anymore. For that case an export into XML would be much better.

The structure then could look like this:

```html
<?xml ... ?>
<products>
    <product>
        <title></title>
        <description></description>
        ...
        <attributes>
            <attribute>
                <title></title>
                <description></description>
                <value></value>
            </attribute>
            <attribute>
                <title></title>
                <description></description>
                <value></value>
            </attribute>
            ...
        </attributes>
    </product>
    ...
</products>
```

But still maybe You could do this using one SQL and export to CSV, but You'll have the attribute names comma concatenated in one column and attribute values comma concatenated in another column... Nothing to be used for automated import nor for importing by phpMyAdmin... Anyway, You could try this:

```
SELECT
    p.product_id,
    p.model,
    pd.name,
    GROUP_CONCAT(ad.name ORDER BY ad.name SEPARATOR ',') AS attributes,
    GROUP_CONCAT(pa.text ORDER BY ad.name SEPARATOR ',') AS values /* <- problem could be with values ordering */
FROM product p
    LEFT JOIN product_attribute pa ON p.product_id = pa.product_id
    LEFT JOIN attribute_description ad ON pa.attribute_id = ad.attribute_id
    LEFT JOIN product_description pd ON p.product_id = pd.product_id
GROUP BY
    p.product_id, p.model, pd.name
ORDER BY
    p.product_id
```

Comment: Actually I do want the attribute values. In short I want to take the attribute group name and make those the column headers then add the values in under the column. The above code pretty much gives me exactly what my original code did.

Comment: Then the desired result cannot be achieved by **one single SQL query**...You have to do it separately - load the product data in one query and then for the concrete product load it's attributes in another query. Where is the `text` column comming from? What values does it contain?

Comment: "text" comes from the product_attribute table. I contains attributes for the products(obviosuly) ranging from html code for links to PDF's to height weight color ect.

Comment: Then the `text` column is why the `GROUP BY` has no effect. OK, maybe I should ask, why do you need to load all the attributes **and it's values** in one row (one entry) with the product data? Maybe we could think of other solution to Your problem...

Comment: In short I need to create a view in which I can export into a csv.
Here is what the query is doing so far, getting closer
[link](http://arvcplumbing.com/data.JPG)

I also posted my new code above.

Comment: We're so close to what I need but just not there. All those are concatenated into one column and I need them broken up into a separate column for each attribute group(color, width, ect).

I looked into pivot tables but I'm not sure if MySQL supports that. Either way I couldn't figure it out.
I also came across this if it might help... I can't figure it out.
[link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c3e0d/31)